# Determining the length of sections of code

Tags: ruby, parsing, code-metrics

Is there a tool that parses a Ruby script (MRI/YARV) and gives statistics of how many lines each module/class/method definition is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by MRI/YARV? A script doesn't have an implementation associated with it. The tool may be associated with a particular implementation, though.

There may be such a tool in the [code metrics](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/code_metrics) section of Ruby Toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

[Saikuro](http://saikuro.rubyforge.org/) will do this. It's also included in [metric_fu](http://metric-fu.rubyforge.org/), which makes it easy to run Saikuro and many other code metrics tools.

(Be careful, the `saikuro` gem is probably not what you want, instead it's `Saikuro` with a capital "S".)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yea I have no idea what the other (lowercase) one is. The description seems similar, but it's not what metric_fu uses, which is what I'm basing which is the "better" one on.